# Responsive menu - Not showing on click

Tags: html, css

I have a simple css responsive menu.

It doesn't open the responsive menu when the hamburger is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="nav-inner">

        <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu"><div>Show Menu</div></label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">


                <div class="menu-primary-container">

                    <ul id="menu" class="menu">

                        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Get involved</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Parents</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Workforce</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Get involved</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Languages</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

Here is my css for the checkbox hamburger:

```
/*  ==============================
    RESPONSIVE NAV BUTTON
============================== */

.show-menu {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    background-color:$dark;

    font-family: $title-regular;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:60px;
    color:$white;
    letter-spacing:1px;

    @media #{$tablet} {
        display:block;
    }
}

.show-menu div {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:25px;
    background-image: url("../includes/icons/hamburger.svg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center left;
}

.nav-wrapper input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}


.nav-wrapper input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}
```

You can see it working here: http://pagedev.co.uk/betterstart/

But since I have made the menu a Wordpress menu it doesn't work.

I cant seem to figure out why its not opening the menu?

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

It was a wordpress issue.

Wordpress wraps it menu in "menu-primary-container"

I added

```
'container' => ''
```

to my array and it solved it.